# Calculate the Minimum Match Length of a Regular Expression in Swift

Tags: regex, swift, algorithm

I wanted to know if anyone has an algorithm for calculating the minimum possible match length of a given regular expression expressed as a string. For example, lets calls this algorithm

[image: φ(r)=Int]

where  [image: r] is the regular expression and the function spits out an integer value. I want to use this algorithm in my app, so I can calculate something like

[image: φ(\bimport\s+)=7]

rather than having to manually tag a "minimum pattern length" piece of metadata to every single regular expression. Any ideas before I go try recreating what seems to be a pretty complicated wheel, myself? I'll enjoy the challenge nonetheless. I presume I'll have to use regular expressions to analyze the regular expression itself. Thanks in advance for the help! I'm look for a solution written in Swift, but a generic version would not hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do would require some work. You will need to develop your own regex parser, and I'm not going to do that for you (I don't know Swift, but a proper parser shouldn't be done with regexes only). I can, however, help with the algorithm.

The way I would imagine this working would be to, step by step, remove and alter the regex until a concrete answer can be reached. Obviously, you shouldn't do this on your only copy of the regex, as this will likely end up destroying the regex.

Here are some steps to take:

- Replace char classes with a `.`. You will need to be careful that you know how Swift's regexes deal with strange syntax, such as `[]`, which in some flavors treats the `]` as a literal, since the syntax would be otherwise invalid.
- Remove max: `(regex part){min`<s>`,max`</s>`}`.

  - Replace `(regex part){min}` with `min` repetitions of `regex part`.
- Remove `*` statements: <s>`(regex part)*`</s>
- Remove any `+` symbols: <s>`(`</s>`regex part`<s>`)+`</s>
- For alternations, find the shortest alternation, and remove all the other ones: <s>`(regex part is long|but this regex part is super duper long|medium regex|`</s>`short`<s>`)`</s>
- Replace a char class with a `.`
- Replace all escaped literals with `.`, even `\n`. Remember, ditching the fancy syntax will make it easier to count how many characters the minimum will be.

This isn't an exhaustive list, but it will hopefully get you started. Something to be cautious about is preemptively removing parenthesis, which may mess up Order of Operations and back-references. And if Swift's regexes feature recursion, this task gets even more difficult.

The other thing to remember is that some regexes may never match anything (but figuring this out may be hard), and the "minimum match length" is fairly meaningless in those cases.

Comment: The tips are much appreciated. Yes, it will require a lot of theory and simply cutting down an expression down to a short string and returning that length

Answer (score 0):

This is in Ruby, not Swift, but [here](https://github.com/tom-lord/regexp-examples) is a tool I wrote which can be used to solve the problem:

```
/import\s+/.examples.map(&:length).min # => 7
```

This tool will work for *all* regular expressions, *except* those which contain look-arounds. (Look-aheads, look-behinds, word boundary anchors, etc.)

You could write a much simpler version of this tool yourself quite easily, if you only wish for it to work on a small subset of the regexp language. However, speaking from experience, creating a "general solution" like this is very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a work in progress but this is what I have so far...

```
public extension String {

    public var minRegexMatchLength: Int {

        let pattern = (self as NSString).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableString

        if let expr = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "((\\(.*?\\))|(\\[.*?\\])|.)[*?]", options: []) {
            expr.replaceMatchesInString(pattern, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (pattern as String).length), withTemplate: "")
        }

        if let expr = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "((\\(.*?\\))|(\\[.*?\\])|.)[+]", options: []) {
            expr.replaceMatchesInString(pattern, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (pattern as String).length), withTemplate: ".")
        }

        if let expr = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\[bswBSW])", options: []) {
            expr.replaceMatchesInString(pattern, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (pattern as String).length), withTemplate: ".")
        }

        if let expr = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\(.*?\\)", options: []) {

            var lengths = [Int]()

            expr.enumerateMatchesInString(pattern as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (pattern as String).length)) 
            { (result: NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) -> Void in
                if let result = result {
                    let substring = pattern.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(result.range.location + 1, result.range.length - 2))
                    var length = substring.length
                    for word in substring.componentsSeparatedByString("|") {
                        if (word.length < length) {
                            length = word.length
                        }
                    }
                    lengths.append(length)
                }
            }

            var match = expr.firstMatchInString(pattern as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (pattern as String).length))
            var i = 0
            while match != nil && i < lengths.count {
                if let range = match?.range {
                    pattern.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withString: "".stringByPaddingToLength(lengths[i], withString: ".", startingAtIndex: 0))
                }
                match = expr.firstMatchInString(pattern as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (pattern as String).length))
                i += 1
            }

        }

        return pattern.length

    }

}
```